# How can I use the EXISTS operator?

Tags: sql-server

Someone maybe can help me to use `EXISTS` operator to check - `ev.tfe_evento = 'Inizio lettura file'` and `ev.tfe_evento = 'lettura file'`. I need to display all files that contain `inizio lettura file` and `lettura file`. The template of code is:

```
SELECT column-names
FROM table-name
WHERE EXISTS  (
    SELECT column-name
    FROM table-name
    WHERE condition
)
```

But how I can change my code below to follow this example?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tflussi_eventi;

SELECT ev.*
INTO tab1
FROM tab1 ev (nolock)
JOIN (
    SELECT lab 
    FROM #lab1
    GROUP BY labname
) tf ON ev.labnameLIKE tf.labname+ '%'
WHERE ev.labevent= 'today' 
AND ev.labevent= 'yesterday'
```

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) If you understand what it does, accept the consequences, and have a good reason to use it, then **at least** use the current / non-deprecated syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I like to use window functions when checking conditions like this. Where you are looking for multiple conditions across the group.

This is not your actual query, just to give you an idea.

With window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fileName
  FROM (SELECT E.*,
               CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN E.tfe_evento = 'lettura file' THEN 1
                                  ELSE 0
                              END
                            ) OVER ( PARTITION BY E.FileName ) = 1
                     AND MAX(CASE WHEN E.tfe_evento = 'Inizio lettura file' THEN 1
                                  ELSE 0
                              END
                            ) OVER ( PARTITION BY E.FileName ) = 1
                     THEN 1
                     ELSE 0
                 END AS FileHasBothEventConds
         FROM EVENT E
       )
 WHERE FileHasBothEventConds = 1;
```

With EXISTS:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fileName
  FROM EVENTS E
 WHERE EXISTS
         ( SELECT 1
             FROM EVENTS E_LF
            WHERE E.fileName = E_LF.fileName
              AND E_FL.tfe_evento = 'lettura file'
         )
   AND EXISTS
         ( SELECT 1
             FROM EVENTS E_ILF
            WHERE E.fileName = E_ILF.fileName
              AND E_ILF.tfe_evento = 'Inizio lettura file'
         )
```

Comment: Wouldn't this make a simple query complex? Select distinct fileName from events where tfe_evento = 'lettura file' or tfe_evento = 'Inizio lettura file' is simpler (and I am not sure that relates to what OP asking).

Comment: @CetinBasoz I guess it depends on how you interpret the question. I was thinking he wanted to see files which had at least one event which matches both of those values. So the "or" would return a file if it only had an event which matched 'lettura file' but none which matched 'Inizio lettura file'

Answer (score 0):

You should use LIKE operator instead of = for that to happen. ie:

```
SELECT ev.*
INTO #tflussi_eventi
FROM tflussi_eventi ev (nolock)
JOIN (
    SELECT FileNameCutoff 
    FROM #FileCutoffTime
    GROUP BY FileNameCutoff
) tf ON ev.tfe_sorgente LIKE tf.FileNameCutoff + '%'
WHERE ev.tfe_evento LIKE '%Inizio lettura file%'
-- Unnecessary because of first criteria 
-- AND ev.tfe_evento = 'lettura file'
AND ev.tfe_data >= @DateToCheck 
AND ev.tfe_data < @DateToCheck + 1 -- not sure what you mean here, if it is datetime, using DateAdd() is safer
```

However, this might suffer from performance, you should think of creating fulltext indexes and use full text search.

EDIT: While it would still suffer because you are not doing a full text search, you might save, maybe negligible time on the joined table which practically has no importance other than "existence check":

```
SELECT ev.*
INTO #tflussi_eventi
FROM tflussi_eventi ev (nolock)
WHERE ev.tfe_evento LIKE '%Inizio lettura file%'
-- Unnecessary because of first criteria 
-- AND ev.tfe_evento = 'lettura file'
AND ev.tfe_data >= @DateToCheck 
AND ev.tfe_data < @DateToCheck + 1 -- not sure what you mean here, if it is datetime, using DateAdd() is safer
and EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM #FileCutoffTime tf
    where ev.tfe_sorgente LIKE tf.FileNameCutoff + '%');
```